# Уроки по 1с программе

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Посоветуйте качественные уроки по 1с программе, мне очень интересно узнать об 1с бухгалтерии и 1с программировании. Буду очень признательным всем дельным советам. В ютубе уже просмотрел несколько курсов но не был удовлетворен качеством контента.

Comment: *Закрывающим*. я не нашёл на сайте вопроса вроде *Книги и учебные ресурсы по продуктам 1С*. Неплохо бы, если б такой был. Спасибо.

Comment: Саша Черных, как у вас дела? честно сказать, я не понял вас...можете написать более детально

Comment: @BakhromMananov, дело в том, что в целом вопросы по поиску книг, учебников, учебных ресурсов и т.д. офтопичны (не по теме) на данном сайте. Для некоторых языков программирования/технологий в качестве исключения есть "каноничные" вопросы (см. в поиске ["книги и учебные ресурсы по"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=книги+и+учебные+ресурсы+по), но по продуктам 1С такого вопроса нет. Такой вопрос можно создать, но уже с готовым ответом с набором ресурсов.

Comment: Самые толковые учебные материалы по программированию в среде 1С:Предприятие это 1C:Предприятие 8.3. Практическое пособие разработчика. Примеры и типовые приемы Авторы: Радченко М. Г., Хрусталева Е. Ю. и другие книги этих авторов. Сам учился по ним.
Вот ссылочка где можно купить http://v8.1c.ru/metod/books/book.jsp?id=441

Answer (score 1):

Кроме уже указанных книг под авторством Радченко можно посмотреть видеоуроки от Чистова, они есть в свободном доступе в Сети. Кроме самого программирования внутри форм, он рассказывает очень плотно и про работу с СКД, и с различными сервисами.